# Creating a list from Nested JSON using Decodable in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, struct, swift4, decodable

I have been able to convert JSON to structs using Swift 4's Decodable, unfortunately i have been unable to do so with a JSON key called "list" , which is a list ([]) that contains other structs.

```
{  
"cod":"200",
"message":0.0061,
"cnt":5,
"list":[  
  {  
     "dt":1522605600,
     "main":{  },
     "weather":[  ],
     "clouds":{  },
     "wind":{  },
     "rain":{  },
     "sys":{  },
     "dt_txt":"2018-04-01 18:00:00"
  },
  {  
     "dt":1522616400,
     "main":{  },
     "weather":[  ],
     "clouds":{  },
     "wind":{  },
     "rain":{  },
     "sys":{  },
     "dt_txt":"2018-04-01 21:00:00"
  },
  {  
     "dt":1522627200,
     "main":{  
        "temp":277.21,
        "temp_min":277.21,
        "temp_max":277.506,
        "pressure":1016.3,
        "sea_level":1023.98,
        "grnd_level":1016.3,
        "humidity":84,
        "temp_kf":-0.3
     },
```

These are my structs, my approach was to make ForecastInstance the overall container which holds a property "list" (like the JSON) that is of type ForecastList (which holds the nested structs).

```
struct ForecastInstance : Decodable {
 let list: [ForecastList]?
}

struct ForecastList : Decodable { 
 let dt : Int?
 let weather : [Weather]?
 let main : Main?
 let wind : Wind?
}

struct Wind : Decodable {
 let speed: Float
}

struct Coord : Decodable {
 let lon : Float
 let lat : Float
}

struct Main : Decodable{
 let temp : Double
 let pressure : Int
 let humidity : Int
 let temp_min: Double
 let temp_max: Double  
}

struct Weather : Decodable{
  let id : Int
  let main: String
  let description: String
  let icon: String
 }
```

When i do the following in the view controller , it fails.

self.currentForecast = try 
JSONDecoder().decode(ForecastInstance.self,from:data!)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please verify your question is formatted properly before posting.

Comment: What is the issue? What error(s) do you get?

Comment: when i try to populate the struct is fails - self.currentForecast = try JSONDecoder().decode(ForecastInstance.self, from: data!)

Comment: Once again: *What error(s) do you get?*

Comment: Post **all** of your code that attempts to decode the JSON you show, as well as the specific error you're getting.

Comment: You know what, that was the answer, i wasn't printing my errors from my catch block. My structs were failing because pressure is of type Int and it wasn't able to wrap the number 1017.41998.  Lesson learned, stick to the basics! Check your errors! Thanks vadian.

Answer (score 0):

This was my error

debugDescription: "Parsed JSON number <1017.42> does not fit in Int.", underlyingError: nil))

Changing the property pressure of type Int to float did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It works in Playground!
Here is a nice article about Codable:
[Swift 4 Decodable: Beyond The Basics](https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375).
I hope it will be helpful.

```
let weatherJSON = """
    {
      "list": [{
      "dt": 1522605600,
      "main": {
                "temp": 30,
                "humidity": 50,
                "pressure": 40
              },
      "weather": ["cloudly"],
      "clouds": {},
      "wind": {},
      "rain": {},
      "sys": {},
      "dt_txt": "2018-04-01 18:00:00"
      }]
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!

    struct Main: Codable {
      let temp: Int?
      let humidity: Int?
      let pressure: Int?
    }

    struct Weather: Codable {
      let dt: Int?
      let main: Main?
      let weather: [String]?
    }

    struct WeatherList: Codable {
      let list: [Weather]?
    }

    let weather = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherList.self, from: weatherJSON)
    let count = "\(weather.list?.count ?? 0)"
    print(count)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your top level struct needs to look like this to mimic your JSON structure. The rest of your structs look fine if you are still getting errors I suggest you relook at those structs as well.

```
struct ForecastInstance : Decodable {
 let cod: String?
 let message: Int?
 let cnt: Int?
 let list: [ForecastList]?
}
```

Comment: sorry the message looked like float or a double, I put INT in mistake and in general.  It's not a string

Comment: beside that i think this is the solution